# React Native - Sending events from Native to JavaScript in AppDelegate (iOS) for remote push notification methods

Tags: objective-c, react-native, push-notification, bridge

I need to implement push notification in react native mobile application from Salesforce Marketing Cloud but SFMC does not have plugin for React Native.So I would try to implement it in the native app delegate and then use it in react native through bridging .How to implement that?How to bridge methods of app delegate like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
    (NSData*)deviceToken
{

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the methods of app delegate from react native directly ,there is no need of bridging if there is no additional work to be done or any dependency with some other tasks implemented in react native. For example I have implemented the push notification in the native part of the code with no dependency in react native javascript code.The whole thing is written in Objective C app dlelegate class and it works fine.The only thing is that the application receives the push notification in the native portion of the code.